# obtain the result or HTTP response of an add operation of ngrx/data

Tags: angular-ngrx-data, ngrx-data

As described in [the entity dataservice documentation](https://ngrx.io/guide/data/entity-dataservice) , the add operation expects an entity to be saved on the backend. What it doesn't say is that it expects the created entity to be returned from the backend (with an ID etc). My backend does that and it works as expected, however

when I tap into the add operation, which returns an Observable, at least my IDE gives me Observable methods to continue... it's best demonstrated with a piece of code

```
this.myEntityService.add(myNewEntity).pipe(
  tap(data => console.log('data:', data))
)
```

Nothing is logged to the console at all.

My question is, how do I get what's returned from the HTTP service? e.g. the entity, persisted to the backend database?

Answer (score 2):

The problem was, I didn't subscribe to the Observable that `add` returns.

I assumed the data is being emitted regardless of a subscription.

So the correct way to receive the result is

```
this.myEntityService.add(myNewEntity).subscribe(data => {
  console.log('data:', data);
});
```

subscribing to it.